# Configuration of WCF End points in Web.config return There was no endpoint listening at that could accept the message

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Well. I have my client layer which has

- Client Contracts project which is class library contains my Service Contracts
- Client Proxies which is class library and implement the Client Contracts
- Client Entities which is class library to be used in client contracts and client proxies
- Client Bootstrapper which is class library to be used for MEF loader purpose
  and I have my web mvc project which controllers are api to call my service 
  and I add refrence for all lient layers in my web project 
  then configure my service in the web.config file as

  ```
     <system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:3167/CountryClient" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              contract="Client.Contracts.ICountryService">
       <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" 
              binding="mexTcpBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </client>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  ```

and my client proxy class

```
namespace Client.Proxies
        {
            [Export(typeof(ICountryService))]
            [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
            public class CountryClient : ClientBase<ICountryService>, ICountryService
            {
                public Entities.Country[] GetAllCountriess(int? Take, int? Skip)
                {
                    return Channel.GetAllCountriess(Take, Skip);
                }
            }
        }
```

and my Contract as following :

```
namespace Client.Contracts
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICountryService : IServiceContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Country[] GetAllCountriess(int? Take, int? Skip);
    }
}
```

when running my web using visual studio : Error happened once i'm in return channel 
Error saying that There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:3167/CountryClient that could accept the message
and the inner exception says: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found
i'm running visual studio as administrator 
I stopped the firewall
the port is not used 
not antivirus or firewall is preventing from connection

my Unit test is working with same configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your service project running in debug when your running your client project test? The url:  http://localhost:3167/CountryClient has to be valid service endpoint. If you have Visual Studio solution with both Service and Client project running then make sure both are executing and enabled. If your service project is a separate project, then make sure you are running that as well.

Comment: yes i tried that and i had error : The Address property on ChannelFactory.Endpoint was null.  The ChannelFactory's Endpoint must have a valid Address specified.

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking you are hosting a service; looks like you are using the service (i.e. service client). Where is your service hosted? Do you have your other service project ( http://localhost:3167/CountryClient) running in debug when you are testing your client?

Comment: actually is class library project in same solution my hosting in the web project 
and so no running while debugging .
am i replying your questions ? 
sorry I'm new in wcf